# "Heavy Plus Sign" ➕ in CSS ::before?

Tags: html, css, text, emoji

I am trying to get the code for the "Heavy Plus Sign" emoji (➕) working in a CSS ::before pseudo-element. The Unicode number for it is U+2795. My [non-working] code is as follows:

```
.plussign::before {
    content: "\12795";
}
```

When I assign an element to use class="plussign", all I see is a little black square (the generic unknown character)

What should I use for the "content" property? The slash-one (\1) method works for all my other emojis. For example, this works for the gemstone (, Unicode U+1F48E):

```
.gem::before {
    content: "\1F48E";
}
```

Why doesn't the "Heavy Plus Sign" emoji work in the same format?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `content: "➕";`, or is there a reason for not doing this?

Comment: @spacerGIF that would require me to save my CSS file in Unicode format, which would risk data loss if I accidentally save it as non-Unicode in the future

Comment: @user3163495 - So...be sure you save (and serve) your files in a reasonable encoding (like UTF-8)?

Comment: The hope of the world!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `\2795` (no leading 1, the codepoint is U+2795, not U+12795):

```css
.plussign::before {
  content: "\2795";
}
```

```html
<div class="plussign"></div>
```

Or of course, the character itself:

```css
.plussign::before {
  content: "➕";
}
```

```html
<div class="plussign"></div>
```